# Is "successful" correct in this context?

Tags: verbing

I have received the following offer to work part time:

> Dear XXX.
>    it was nice talking to you, hope things will be good with all of us.
>    we offered a part time job.

I wanted to send my response.

I tried this:

> Dear Ms.XXX
>    I agree to your offer.
>    I will do my best to successful the job.

Did I use "successful" correctly?

Comment: The first line should start with a capital **I**. It is also incomplete because it does not say what you have received an offer to work part time, as. You built up to it but, did not finish.

Comment: Looks like the offer is also a non-native speaker.  That said, you would typically `accept` an offer, and try to `be successful at`, or `to succeed at` the job

Comment: Gus's speculation is plausible, and his suggestion is good. *To succeed at the job* is to make yourself succeed (at the job). However, if you want to say that you want the job (probably a short-term project) turn out to be successful, you might say *to make the job successful* instead.

Comment: @DamkerngT. In the US, *part-time job* does not generally suggest a short-term job but a job with reduced hours, and even more reduced pay and benefits. A short-term job would be described as *temporary* and might be either full- or part-time.

Comment: Words ending in *-ful* are most often adjectives (*successful, beautiful, peaceful, grateful, awful*), though sometimes they're nouns (*handful, mouthful, fistful*), and in nonstandard English they're occasionally adverbs (*\*awful*).

Answer (score 3):

*Successful* is an adjective, but the construction you use, “I will do my best **to X**”, calls for a verb. You should say

> I will do my best **to be** successful in the job    *OR*
>   I will do my best **to succeed** at the job.

Note that, as Gus says, one generally *accepts* a job or an offer after the terms of employment (pay, hours, duties, &c) have been *agreed on* between you and the employer. In the expression *agree to* it is rare that *to* acts as a preposition, except in circumstances where you are accepting non-negotiated conditions; usually *to* is the infinitive marker:

> He agreed **to speak** at the dinner.
>   We agreed **to meet** again in three weeks.